# java slf4j fails in intellij(no log provider) but runs ok in command line, why?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, slf4j, provider

I've got an intellij(2018.2) maven project on mac, having following code:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class useSlf {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(useSlf.class);
        logger.info("Hello World");
    }
}
```

My pom.xml get this dependency:

```
<dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.25</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Well under command line it runs:

```
$java  useSlf
2018-11-03 19:53:59,137 [myid:] - INFO  [main:useSlf@7] - Hello World
```

But when I tried to run it in intellij it gives:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_111.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -
```

Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath ...... useSlf

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further 
details.
```

This is weird. In my mac, bash checks:

```
echo $CLASSPATH
```

There's no log provider in my $CLASSPATH and my java program runs well, this is odd, I expect I should give a provider jar here like:

```
java -cp ~/Downloads/slf4j-simple-1.8.0-beta2.jar:. useSlf
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
    at useSlf.main(useSlf.java:6)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 1 more
```

My questions:

1. My command line results is so weird: If I don't give provider jar, it works; when I give the simple log provider, it gives exception! How to explain this?
2. I tried to add this simple log jar in "Project structue-->library" for my project, and run again. Still doesn't solve the problem. How can I make it work in intellij?

Comment: What is the contents of your `$CLASSPATH`, then? You seem to be able to run your class without any explicit classpath, so there must be something in there.

Comment: Try to add `compile` scope to maven dependency.